# Arduino Leonardo keyboard.print keeps printing equal sign

Tags: keyboard

I am currently working on a DIY controller for Train Sim World. I am relatively new to the Arduino and the C programming language. My code is structured to look for button presses or PS2 joystick inputs and print a specific character for each button. I have also included a kill switch on pin 3. However when I run the code and open Notepad to see the results, the Arduino keeps printing the `=` character even if pin 3 is not pulled low. After I pull pin 3 low and press a button, there is a delay of about two seconds during which the `=` character keeps being printed over and over again, and after these 2 seconds elapse the Arduino prints the character attributed to the button several times before returning to printing `=` over and over again.

What can I do to fix this?

```cpp
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
    pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(1, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(6, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(9, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(10, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(11, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(12, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
bool pantograph = 0;
void loop() {
    while (digitalRead(3) == LOW) {
        Keyboard.write("M");
        if (digitalRead(1) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("W");
        } else if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("S");
        } else if (digitalRead(0) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("Q");
        } else if (digitalRead(5) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("Y");
        } else if (digitalRead(6) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("T");
        } else if (digitalRead(7) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("G");
        } else if (digitalRead(8) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("K");
        } else if (digitalRead(9) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("Z");
        } else if (digitalRead(10) == LOW) {
            if (pantograph == 0) {
                Keyboard.write("P");
            } else {
                Keyboard.write("O");
            }
        } else if (digitalRead(11) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write(9);
        } else if (digitalRead(12) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write("N");
        } else if (digitalRead(13) == LOW) {
            Keyboard.write(32); 
        } else if (analogRead(A0) > 700) {
            Keyboard.write(93);
        } else if (analogRead(A0) < 200) {
            Keyboard.write(91);
        } else if (analogRead(A1) > 700) {
            Keyboard.print(39);
        } else if (analogRead(A1) < 200) {
            Keyboard.print(59);
        } else if (analogRead(A2) > 700) {
            Keyboard.print("A");
        } else if (analogRead(A2) < 200) {
            Keyboard.print("D");
        }
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd cause it but I think you should have a `Keyboard.begin()` at the end of the setup function.

Comment: @PeterJ unfortunately it didn't work. Same thing happens as I've described before. However by moving the delay inside `while` the program slows down to printing once every second, as expected, and the buttons' associated characters only print once, but the program still prints the "=" over and over again

Comment: did you read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The method `write` with one parameter takes char not string. Use `write('W')`, not `write("W");`